# Deleting Firestore data from another fragment android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an application where I have a wishlist checkbox(heart icon) on my recyclerview items at Home Fragment, So when the user clicks on the heart icon it adds that particular item to the Wishlist Fragment, and when the user again clicks it, I want it to delete the item from the wishlist fragment. While adding the item it is working properly but when I try to delete it, it is not working and gives me a null pointer error.

CODE IS HERE

```
  holder.wishlist.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

            Boolean isCheck = compoundButton.isChecked();

            //CODE TO ADD THE ITEM TO THE WISHLIST THROUGH HOME FRAGMENT
            if(isCheck)
            {

                firebaseFirestore.collection("wishlistDetails").document(uid).set(wishMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            holder.wishlist.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_filled);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "item added to wishlist" + pos , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {


                    }
                });

              //CODE TO DELETE THE ITEM FROM WISHLIST THROUGH HOME FRAGMENT  
            }else {

                firebaseFirestore.collection("wishlistDetails").document(wishlist_models.get(position).getUid())
                        .delete()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                Toast.makeText(context, "item removed from wishlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
```

**WISHLIST MODEL CODE**

```
public class Wishlist_Model {

private List<String> images;
private String name;
private String email;
private String delete;
private String uid;

public Wishlist_Model()  {
}

public Wishlist_Model(List<String> images, String name, String email, String delete, String uid) {
    this.images = images;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.delete = delete;
    this.uid = uid;

}



public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getDelete() {
    return delete;
}

public void setDelete(String delete) {
    this.delete = delete;
}

public List<String> getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(List<String> images) {
    this.images = images;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}
```

}

**FIRESTORE COLLECTION**

[image]

ERROR IT IS THROWING

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: can you please share error msg?

Comment: remove this -->  wishlist_models = new ArrayList<>(); from your code

Comment: @AdityaNandardhane brother now it is throwing     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: @AlexMamo no sir

Comment: Then what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: yes sir it is giving me null pointer exception

Comment: so as shown in the code above sir i am trying to add data to wishlist fragment through home fragment if someone clicks on the wishlist icon in home frag. and when someone uncheck it i want it to delete

Comment: Can you upload your wishlist _model. And Firestore collections details.

Comment: @Younus please check

Comment: I suggest this error is because the position: 2 is in int(number). Try to change into string.

Comment: but sir this same deleting method is working fine in wishlist fragment

Comment: @Younus but when i am trying to delete it through home fragment then it is giving me error

Comment: Try to delete it from whishlist fragment.

Comment: @Younus yes it is working fine through wishlist fragment.

Comment: Now I am answering. It will help another person.

Comment: @AlexMamo sir can you help me with that?

Comment: @AdityaNandardhane hey brothr can you please help me with this??

Comment: Did Younus's answer solve your problem?

Comment: @AlexMamo no sir it did not solve the problem

Comment: As I see, it has three upvotes. Why isn't solving your problem?